# Error in Arabic reader project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am build a NDK application from the Arabic reader open source project.And i successfuly buld project and imprted into eclipse work Space.But when I run the application the following log Shown in my logcat

i am sure that iam build all the nesseserry .so file

1.libNativeFormats-v4.so
2.libLineBreak-v2.so
3.libDeflatingDecompressor-v3.so

**My logcat as follows**

```
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420): Process: net.sourceforge.arabicReader:configService, PID: 3420
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "atof" referenced by "libNativeFormats-v4.so"...
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:333)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at java.lang.System.load(System.java:512)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at org.geometerplus.android.util.NativeLibraryUtil.tryLoad(NativeLibraryUtil.java:66)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at org.geometerplus.android.util.NativeLibraryUtil.init(NativeLibraryUtil.java:42)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReaderApplication.onCreate(FBReaderApplication.java:29)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4730)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:175)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
04-21 11:50:11.256: E/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help could be appreciated !! Thanks

Comment: What API level are you targeting, what NDK are you using, and what is your device OS?

Comment: sorry to respond lite. I am solved my problem .Thanks for your responds